# Clicking a button in web app reveals inputs behind button, then unintentionally focuses on input

Tags: android, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a button(div.button) with a form(hidden) behind it. On clicking the button, the button hides, and then the form is shown (in that order) e.g:

```
$('.button').on('touchend',function(){

    $('.button').hide();
    $(form).show();

});
```

That works ok, but the problem is that if I tap the button on the phone in the same place where an input will show, that input will be already selected and ready to type into. Which is unwanted. It is like the button is being held down... or pushing through the layer. This functionality doesn't happen on my desktop.

The button is in a div (absolute positioned) and sits above the form (also absolute positioned) with the button having a higher z-index.

Any ideas how to fix this? Does the mobile browser 'touchend' do some sort of holding down on that part of the screen?

**Here is a jsfiddle of the issue:** http://jsfiddle.net/m6BRP/2/

I have also tried putting the form showing function inside the return function so that the show function only loads after the hide function has complete - but this has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems verbose, but try this:

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('css-selector');
    form.hide();
    $('.button').on('touchend', function () {
        $(this).hide(function () {
           form.show();
        });
    });
});
```

By wrapping the whole thing in $(), you know that the dom loads before you attach events, so that all the events work.  By hiding the form, you are sure that nothing can "bleed under" the button, although I am not sure what could be causing that.  Finally, but showing the form inside of the hide callback with a timeout, you are sure that it is only showing once the touch event is over and the button is gone.

If it works, try to take bits of the complexity out...

/** edit: removed superfluous timeout **/

Comment: So because there is a 1000ms delay before the form show function. But what your solution showed me is that the hide() function isn't an immediate hide, but is animating by default. I'm guessing this has something to do with it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know how it is possible to achieve the same result without a timer of 1000ms? I don't want a 1s delay between page loads just to avoid this selecting of the input.

Answer (score 2):

I think stopPropagation() is what you need:

```
$('#face').on('touchend',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#face').hide()
    $('#under').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m6BRP/8/

I tried it on my phone just in case, it worked for me.

Comment: I was hopeful, but mine selects the input when i click the text on my phone. What phone are you using btw?